# Relating spactra of matrices that are connected by a rectangular orthogonal transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, diagonalization, orthogonal-matrices

Consider a diagonalizable square matrix $A$ of size $N-\text{by}-N$. Now I want to construct another matrix $B = T^T \cdot A \cdot T$, where $T$ is an orthogonal matrix of size $N-\text{by}-M$ (where $M < N$), which obeys $T^T \cdot T = I$, so $B$ is a square $M-\text{by}-M$ matrix.

Provided that I know the spectral decomposition of $A = S_{A}^{\:} \cdot D_{A}^{\:} \cdot S^{-1}_{A}$, can I say something about the spectrum of $B$? Or literally nothing?

Comment: if $A$ is real symmetric, then look up Cauchy Eigenvalue Interlacing

Comment: Hey! I heard some stuff about interlacing related to low-rank perturbations of real matrices (thanks to Gilbert Strang!), but in the most favorable case for me A is complex, and not even complex symmetric. I believe that what you mention may be applicable when A is complex symmetric, and when real and imag parts commute. Anyway, thanks for the comment!

Comment: complex symmetric won't do it.  You'd need complex Hermitian to apply Interlacing

Comment: yes, I understand that in a general case it might be not applicable, but in some special cases  like specific complex symmetric it might be. For instance, if the real, and imaginary parts of the matrix commute, then they are diagonalized simultaneously, and THEN you can split the problem into two: for real, and imag parts, and both cases are tractable then, as they are symmetric :)
Anyways, are you aware whether there are any  generalization for cases that are worse? Like non-normal matrices? And if not interlacing there might be some bounds on how eigenvalues might change.

Comment: It isn't even clear what you are asking.  E.g. you wrote $B = T^T A  T$ and call $T$ orthogonal (it isn't since non-square) but clarify $T^TT = I_M$. But since you are working over $\mathbb C$, the standard choice would be $B = T^*A T$ with $T^*T=I_M$... now $G:=O_n\big(\mathbb C\big)$ *is* a group and you could take the first $M$ columns from $g\in G$ to get $T^TT = I$ but I suspect you want to do that to  $g \in U_n\big(\mathbb C\big)$. Put differently do you actually mean to use "orthogonal" wrt to standard inner product or the dot product?  They are different forms over $\mathbb C$.

Comment: The trick is: despite the fact that $A$ is over the complex numbers, $T$ in my particular case is real, which is why I take $T^T$. Sorry, I did not clarify that from the beginning.